# trigger a pipeline job from dockerhub webhooks

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i have a docker repository for which i have set up webhooks. I have a jenkins pipeline job for which build trigger configurations are following.
[image]

i want this job to be triggered if a new image is pushed to my docker repository. i have installed CloudBees Docker Hub/Registry Notification plugin as well. Following is webhook history which shows that hooks are being sent successfully but still the job is not being triggered. 
[image]